# Fixed width sidebar in responsive design not working why?

Tags: html, css

For an unknown reason it is not working as it should work..

I am using this code as example:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="sidebar">Static LEFT sidebar</div>
    <div id="content">Main content: fluid div.<br/>Width is automatically adjusted between 300px and 700px</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

#wrap { margin: 0px; padding: 10px; max-width:1000px; min-width:500px; margin: 0 auto;}

#header {background: #0f0;}

#sidebar {width: 200px; float: left; height: 200px; background: #ddd;}

#content {margin-left: 210px; min-height: 100px; background: #ddd;}

#footer {clear:both; background: #0f0;}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/56erp1my/20/) (this is how should work)

there you can see that sidebar is completely below ? why ?

what is wrong ?

thank you

Comment: You last div in the code is not correct. Change the code part of your question.

Comment: code where ? jsfiddle or ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work if its copy pasted, Try this

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="sidebar">Static LEFT sidebar</div>
    <div id="content">Main content: fluid div.<br/>Width is automatically adjusted between 300px and 700px</div>
   <div> <!--closed div here-->

<style type="text/css"> <!--added style tag-->
#wrap { margin: 0px; padding: 10px; max-width:1000px; min-width:500px; margin: 0 auto;}

#header {background: #0f0;}

#sidebar {width: 200px; float: left; height: 200px; background: #ddd;}

#content {margin-left: 210px; min-height: 100px; background: #ddd;}

#footer {clear:both; background: #0f0;}
</style>
```

EDIT: I should not be doing this, But here is a code which will work for you

```
#page-body-inner {

  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}

#sidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

add your own css code to respective ids, the above code will make your divs side by side

Comment: i saw the code in fiddle and corrected your code, pls check

Comment: jsfiddle code is fine... you should see live example.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems in your CSS:

1. You have specified `margin-right: 260px;` for `#page-body-inner` div. Get rid of that.
2. You need to add `float: left;` to your `#page-body-inner` div.
3. Lastly, the width for `#page-body-inner` div is too large, so the side bar and the div can not fit in a single row. Try to decrease the width.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't expect your sidebar will float main container box from right side, if you defined margin-right: 265px; for your main container. It means this area is already taken by main container and it's impossible to put sidebar over there.

Instead of doing this, you should try set correct width for both blocks.
For example:

```
    #page-body-inner {
        float: left;
        width: calc(100% - 260px);
        margin-right: 0;
    }
```

```
    #sidebar {
        float: left;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If you will put your sidebar at first place it will work, yes. 
However, if you'll put sidebar as second element, there is already space taken by main container:
https://jsfiddle.net/xtgzru3m/

Your code is buggy and you shouldn't do it this way.

Answer (score -1):

delate margin-right:260px,belongs to the div whitch id is page-body-inner

Comment: and what I get with this ?